# Unusual pattern in the distribution of primes of form $4n\pm1, 6n\pm 1$ [Chebyshev's bias]

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have recently noticed an unusual pattern in the distribution of odd primes.

Each one of the following sets contains approximately half of all odd primes:

- $A_n=\{4k+1: 0\leq k\leq n\}=\{1,5,9,13,\dots,4n+1\}$
- $B_n=\{4k+3: 0\leq k\leq n\}=\{3,7,11,15,\dots,4n+3\}$
- $C_n=\{6k+1: 0\leq k\leq n\}=\{1,7,13,19,\dots,6n+1\}$
- $D_n=\{6k+5: 0\leq k\leq n\}=\{5,11,17,23,\dots,6n+5\}$

More precisely:

- Let $P(S)$ denote the number of odd primes in the set $S$
- Let $\pi(x)$ denote the number of odd primes smaller than $x$

Then for every sufficiently large value of $n$:

- ${P(A_n)}\approx{P(B_n)}\approx\frac12\pi(4n+4)$
- ${P(C_n)}\approx{P(D_n)}\approx\frac12\pi(6n+6)$

Now, all of this is pretty easy to observe (though probably not so easy to prove).

The following facts are subsequently obvious for every sufficiently large $n$ as well:

- ${P(A_n)}\leq{P(B_n)}\implies{P(A_n)}\leq\frac12\pi(4n+4)\leq{P(B_n)}$
- ${P(A_n)}\geq{P(B_n)}\implies{P(A_n)}\geq\frac12\pi(4n+4)\geq{P(B_n)}$
- ${P(C_n)}\leq{P(D_n)}\implies{P(C_n)}\leq\frac12\pi(6n+6)\leq{P(D_n)}$
- ${P(C_n)}\geq{P(D_n)}\implies{P(C_n)}\geq\frac12\pi(6n+6)\geq{P(D_n)}$

This is because $A_n$ and $B_n$ as well as $C_n$ and $D_n$ are "complementary" to each other:

- The set ${A_n}\cap{B_n}$ is empty, and the set ${A_n}\cup{B_n}$ contains all odd primes smaller than $4n+4$
- The set ${C_n}\cap{D_n}$ is empty, and the set ${C_n}\cup{D_n}$ contains all odd primes smaller than $6n+6$

---

Nevertheless, for almost every value of $n$:

- ${P(A_n)}\leq{P(B_n)}$
- ${P(C_n)}\leq{P(D_n)}$

The graphs and table below provide some empirical evidence:

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
 range     | odd primes | cases where either P(A)>P(B) or P(C)>P(D)
-----------|------------|-------------------------------------------
 10000     | 1228       | 0
 100000    | 9591       | 1
 1000000   | 78497      | 239
 10000000  | 664578     | 239
 100000000 | 5761454    | 1940
```

---

I would expect primes to be equally distributed between $A_n$ and $B_n$ and between $C_n$ and $D_n$.

In other words, I would expect:

- [Number of primes of the form $4k+1$] $\approx$ [Number of primes of the form $4k+3$]
- [Number of primes of the form $6k+1$] $\approx$ [Number of primes of the form $6k+5$]

But since the empirical evidence above suggests otherwise, my questions are:

1. Is this indeed the case, or do they become equally distributed on a larger range?
2. If this is indeed the case, what research has been conducted attempting to explain it?

Thanks

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165887/number-of-primes-with-1-pmod-6-vs-number-of-primes-with-1-pmod-6.

Comment: @daniel: 1. It's from May 2012 (!!!), so excuse me for possibly not remembering to have posted this allegedly "almost identical" question (as well as the comment below it). 2. I read that question again, and I disagree with you on the fact that it is almost identical to this one. 3. I am guessing that at the time, I briefly **looked into** (quoting from the comment) "Prime Number Races", but **with relation** to what I had asked **at the time**. Since it is not the same as what I am asking here, I did not "digest" the pieces of information that were relevant to what I am asking now...

Comment: @daniel: ... (obviously, since I didn't know that I was going to ask it). 4. Where on MSE have I already asked this question? 5. What is GRH-AP?

Comment: @daniel: OK, so as I already said, that question (IMHO) is not the same as this one. In the first one I was asking about the maximal difference between the number of primes $\pm1\pmod6$. In this one, I am specifically stating my observation that one type appears to be "more abundant" than the other, and I am asking whether or not the observation is correct, and if correct - then what are the reasons for this "asymmetry". I do not find these two questions "almost identical", hence, I did not recall asking an almost identical question in the past. If you don't mind, please revoke your down-vote.

Comment: @daniel: I understand, but I think that the questions are slightly related and nothing more. Can you give a link to that paper (might have been in one of your previous comments here, but you seem to be deleting them every once in a while for some reasons). Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos The question is from May 2014, not May 2012 (!!!).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The phenomenon you observe is real. This is known, the case for $4$,  as [Chebyshev's bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias)
Another relevant keyword is Shanks–Rényi race problem.

["Prime number races"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408319v1) by Granville and Martin is a fantastic introduction to this circle of ideas.

But, let me include some basic information here (more-or-less [self-plagiarizing an MO-answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/128125/)).

On a rough scale the frequency counts of primes congruent $1$ and $3$ modulo $4$  are the same; both counting functions are asymptotic to $\frac{1}{2} \text{li}(x)$ with error terms essentially as commonly know from  the prime counting function.  This is the well-know Prime Number Theorem for arithmetic progressions (mentioned by Dietrich Burde).

However, if one compares the exact counts of primes congruent to $1$ and $3$ modulo $4$ respectively, let me call the respective counting functions $\pi_1(x)$ and $\pi_3(x)$, then one notes (at least at the start) that there are more congruent to $3$ than congruent to $1$, so $\pi_3(x) > \pi_1(x)$, an observation made by Chebyshev. However, Littlewood showed that the difference $\pi_3(x) - \pi_1(x)$ can also be negative, and even is infinitely often essentially as negative as it can get (under  the assumption that both should not deviate from $\text{li}(x)/2$ by more than $\sqrt{x}$ and a little).

So, now one might think that one just came across a phenomenon of small numbers, as you said, with this initial bias however this is *not* so there *is a bias* in the distribution.

If one defines $P$ to be the set of all integers such that  $\pi_3(x) > \pi_1(x)$ then these are *not* "half of the integers". 
[Rubinstein and Sarnak proved](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1048515870) (under widely believe conjectures on zeros of L-functions, GRH and GSH) that the logarithmic density of this set, that is the limit of 
$$ 
\frac{1}{\log x} \sum_{n \in P} \frac{1}{n}
$$
is $0.9959...$, so *quite* close to $1$ though not equal to $1$ so "almost all" is perhaps too strong.

Comment: _Almost_ almost all?

Comment: Thanks quid. Based on the fact that one is more likely to "come across" a prime of the form $p\equiv5\pmod6$ than a prime of the form $p\equiv1\pmod6$, can we infer that one is more likely to "come across" a semi-prime of the form $n\equiv1\pmod6$ than a semi-prime of the form $n\equiv5\pmod6$?

Comment: For example, if the chances are $60:40$ in favor of prime $p\equiv5\pmod6$, then the chances are $52:48$ in favor of semi-prime $n\equiv1\pmod6$, right?

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately I do not have an answer to your question; it might be known though. The problem which races are biased in which way is subtle. If the bias was as strong as you propose one should be able to say something like this; but the bias is only in lower order terms so the situation is less clear.

Answer (score 5):

The [Dirichlet density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_density) of primes $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and of primes $p\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ is both equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, but the number of primes up to $x$ in both classes can differ. This is what is meant by *Prime number races* ( see the answer of quid).

Comment: So what do you mean by *Dirichlet density*? Sounds to me like their density should not be equal.

Comment: @barakmanos when you divide the number of primes congruent 1 modulo 4 less than x, by the number of all primes less than x, and call this $d_1(x)$ then $d_1(x)$ goes to $1/2$ as $x$ to infinity. In this  asymptotic sense the counts are equal; I now included some more details in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across something that I would expect to provide to provide evidence for the fact that more primes can be written as 6n+5 than 6n+1. Hopefully the way that I describe this will make sense, though I am not expecting it to be perfectly legibile.
First, its important to note that any number 6n+3 is divisible by three and therefore not prime. Also, 6n+2 and 6n+4 are also not prime because they are even. Therefore the set of primes that can be written as 6n+1 is equivalent to the set of primes that can be written as 3n+1 (bear with me here). In a similar way, the set of primes that can be written as 6n+5 is equivalent to the set of primes that can be written as 3n-1.
All numbers that can be written as either 3n+1 or 3n-1 will be prime, a power of a prime, or a composite number. Any number 3n+1 raised to a power will give another number 3m+1. Any number 3n-1 raised to an odd power will give another number 3m-1, but raised to an even power would give a number 3m+1. 
It would therefore make sense that fewer numbers 3n+1 will be prime, compared to those written 3n-1.
This thinking, however, assumes that composite numbers are equally distributed between numbers 3n+1 and 3n-1.