# More primes of the form $6k-1$ than $6k+1$

Tags: prime-numbers

> Let $a_n:= $ number of primes of the form $6k-1$ and $\le n$
>
> and $b_n:= $ number of primes of the form $6k+1$ and $\le n$.

I was playing with my computer and noticed that $a_n\ge b_n$ for all $n\le 10^8$. Can this be extrapolated for larger integers?
Also it was evident that $a_n-b_n$ grows. Is this unbounded?

Comment: http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf

Comment: I lost to team 1. Ha Ha

Comment: See [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1066401/131263) and [this related question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/165887/27456).