# Show $\sum \frac{1}{p}(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, prime-numbers

Show that the sum
$$\sum \frac{(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}{p}$$
converges, where the sum is taken over all odd primes.

This problem was on an old Harvard qualifying exam. Is there a reasonably elementary way to solve it?

Comment: Not sharing any thoughts, insights, progress, attempts???

Comment: I don't have any. It's from an old Harvard qualifying exam.

Comment: By the way, I believe that you are essentially asking about the ratio between primes of the form $4n+1$ and primes of the form $4n+3$. If I'm not mistaken, there's a conjecture about generally more primes of one of these forms.

Comment: Indeed. But this was on an exam, so there's a way to do it that doesn't require solving an open conjecture.

Comment: There you go: [an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1066412/131263) I received on a question which I think is more or less equivalent to yours (if I understand it correctly), given by @quid.

Comment: BTW, despite what I've mentioned on the first comment, I don't think that there's any need to down-vote this question.

Comment: Slight nitpick: the term $p=2$ is obviously undefined.

Answer (score 3):

We have that $\left(p-1\right)/2$ is odd iff $p\equiv3\textrm{ mod }4$ and is even iff $p\equiv1\textrm{ mod }4$. Let $$A\left(N\right)=\sum_{p\leq N}\left(-1\right)^{\left(p-1\right)/2}=\left|\left\{ p\leq N:\, p\equiv1\textrm{ mod }4\right\} \right|-\left|\left\{ p\leq N:\, p\equiv3\textrm{ mod }4\right\} \right|=\pi\left(N;4,1\right)-\pi\left(N;4,3\right).$$
 By partial summation $$\sum_{p\leq N}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(p-1\right)/2}}{p}=\frac{A\left(N\right)}{N}+\int_{3}^{N}\frac{A\left(t\right)}{t^{2}}dt$$
 then observe that, by prime number theorem on arithmetic progression (using the fact that $4<\left(\log\left(N\right)\right)^{C}$
  for some $C>0$) $$\pi\left(N;4,1\right)-\pi\left(N;4,3\right)=O\left(\frac{N}{\phi(4)\log\left(N\right)^{2}}\right)$$ where $\phi(.)$ is the Euler totient function, so $$\sum_{p\leq N}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(p-1\right)/2}}{p}=O\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(N\right)^{2}}+\int_{3}^{N}\frac{1}{t\log\left(t\right)^{2}}dt\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(N\right)^{2}}+\frac{1}{\log\left(N\right)}+ \frac{1}{\log(3)}\right)=O\left(1\right).$$
 Now take $N\longrightarrow\infty.$

Comment: How do we know $\pi(N;4,1)-\pi(N;4,3)=O(N/\log^2N)$? Dirichlet on AP's only gives $O(N)$...

Comment: @barto Note that if we have $\pi\left(N;q,a\right)$ with $q<\log(N)^{C}$ for some $C>0$, holds $$\pi\left(N;q,a\right)=\frac{N}{\phi\left(q\right)\log N}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(N\right)}\right)\right).$$

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Could you give a reference?

Comment: @barto Page 7, display (11.9.2) here: http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/Courses/Chapter11.pdf

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but it seems you show that it is $O(1)$. How does this show convergence?  I mean $\sum_{n\le N}(-1)^n$ is also $O(1)$. (I think you method is good, but there might be a small change to be made.)

Comment: @quid The fact that the series is $O(1)$ implies that is convergent. In other therms, we have $$\sum_{p\leq N}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(p-1\right)/2}}{p}<C$$
 for some $C>0$ and $C$ is indipendent by $N$.
  So if you take the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$
  we have$$\sum_{p}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(p-1\right)/2}}{p}<C$$ so the series is convergent.

Comment: This is true for sequences with positive terms but not in general. Please have a look at the example I gave, I think it is clearly bounded and clearly not convergent, so there must be some additional consideration in your case.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the point. The series is convergent (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html) and why it doesn't work in my case? Yes, there is an error in my previous comment, because I should write $$\left|\sum_{p}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(p-1\right)/2}}{p}\right|<C.$$ The alternating series $A(N)$ is $O(N/\log(N)^{2})$, which tends to infinity when $N \rightarrow \infty$.