# Are there useful estimations of the distribution of primes congruent to $3\pmod 4$?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Let $q_n$ be the $n$-th number in 
$\{\,p\in\mathbb P\,|\,p\equiv 3\pmod 4\,\}$ and define 
$r_n=\frac{\pi^2}{4}n\ln n$, then
$1\leq n\leq 1973\implies r_n\leq q_n$.

[image]

$\qquad\quad q_n$ *is the blue curve and* $r_n$ is the red curve.

But $r_{1974}=36958>36947=q_{1974},\;r_{10000}-q_{10000}=2989$ and 
$r_{100000}-q_{100000}=93029$. For $n>1800$ prime numbers of this form starts to come closer and the nice formula for $r_n$ loose all its accuracy.

```
 n   qn   rn
 1    3    0
 2    7    3
 3   11    8
 4   19   14
 5   23   20
 6   31   27
 7   43   34
 8   47   41
 9   59   49
10   67   57
11   71   65
12   79   74
13   83   82
14  103   91
15  107  100
16  127  109
17  131  119
18  139  128
19  151  138
20  163  148
```

> Are there known formulas to estimate $q_n$?

---

Guided by a comment I managed to look up the formula 
$\pi(x;d,a)\sim\frac{x}{\varphi(d)\ln x}$, where 
$\varphi(d)$ is the same for primes of the form $nd+a$. In this case  $\varphi(4)=2$ is the constant to replace $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$.

The formula above comes from [A Computational Introduction to Number Theory and Algebra, Victor Shoup](https://books.google.se/books?id=pWFdMf5hb5oC&pg=PA122&dq=estimation%20of%20distribution%20of%20primes%20congruent%20to%203%20modulo%204&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBgcuP_a7OAhVGkywKHbjcBdAQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=estimation%20of%20distribution%20of%20primes%20congruent%20to%203%20modulo%204&f=false)

Comment: Half and half. So not particularly close to $\pi^2/4$.With the natural generalization to primes congruent to $a\pmod{m}$,  where $\gcd(a,m)=1$.

Comment: I have previously posted a question which might be of interest to you,  regarding the distribution of primes that are equal $1\pmod4$ vs the distribution of primes that are equal $3\pmod4$, and regarding the distribution of primes that are equal $1\pmod6$ vs the distribution of primes that are equal $5\pmod6$. It's a little long, but in case you want to have a look, you can find it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1066401/131263).

Comment: [This paper](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf) may be of interest to you.

Comment: @barakmanos: I must have seen your post before because I upvoted it. But now, when my own interest is right on the same spot, I find your approach very interesting. Especially the asymmetry between different congruence classes, beyond the invarians in the extended Gauss formula in the end of my question.

Comment: @user170039: Thanks for that interesting link!